# Problems Removing the url from text using java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to remove url from some strings that i get from twitter.
The code i use is:

```
test.replaceAll("http.*?\\s", ""));
```

The problem is that when i try there are some strings it doesn't work, for example:

```
String cuatro = ("#TodosPorKiKi El plan de flia solidaria No Puede exceder los 6meses. La justicia de Santa Fe lo abandonó 2 años y ahora\r\n" + 
            "Quieren hacerse los legalistas\r\n" + 
            "#Verguenza  Respete los derechos del niño @MiguelLifschitz @DataLifschitz https//t/MUY0bj2qMT");

output:
```

I dont`t know why for some text it works and for other doesn't

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: Since a url is without spaces you need to split the string to an array of words using `str.split("..", ' ')` and remove the element that starts with using `str.startsWith(&quot;..&quot;)` methodhttp:// or https://

Comment: Since your regex contains `\\s` (whitespace) at the end, that means it won't work if the URL is at the end of input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.*?` in your regex will look for a minimal zone, which will be none in fact, so it won't be able to find a space after, and it's not the good way to do it

---

You need to focus on 2 simple properties

- url starts with `http`
- url does not contain `spaces`

So your regex can be: `http\S*` (*http* followed by *multiple non-space* char)

```
String cuatro = ("#TodosPorKiKi El plan de flia solidaria No Puede exceder los 6meses. https//t/MUY0bj2qMT" +
            " La justicia de Santa Fe lo abandonó 2 años y ahora\r\n" +
            "Quieren hacerse los legalistas\r\n  https//t/MUY0bj2qMT" +
            "#Verguenza  Respete los derechos del niño @MiguelLifschitz @DataLifschitz https//t/MUY0bj2qMT");
String cleaned = cuatro.replaceAll("http\\S*", ""); 
System.out.println(cleaned);    // I added multiple url in the String, for you can see it remvoes all
```